# Update table if user clicks edit link

Tags: php

Im trying to get my query to update upon user click
This one here works but it doesnt wanna update I Says Query Empty

I edited the code as follows

```
  if ($action == "edit"){
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $result=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',email='$email' WHERE id=$id");
     $sql = mysql_query($result) or die (mysql_error());
}

$sql=mysql_query("select * from user where id='$id'");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){                                             
    $id = $row['id'];
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
    $email = $row['email'];


    echo("<form name='edit' method='post' action='?action=edit'>");
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='?action=edit'>");
    echo("<table class=main cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5 >");
    echo("<tr><td>Name: </td><td align='right'><input type='text' name='first_name' value='$first_name'></td></tr>");
    echo("<tr><td>Surname: </td><td align='right'><input type='text'  name='last_name' value='$last_name'></td></tr>");
    echo("<tr><td>Email: </td><td align='right'><input type='text' name='email' value='$email'></td></tr>");
    echo("<tr><td></td><td><div align='right'><input type='submit'></div></td></tr>");
    echo("</table>");
}
       }  


echo("<br>");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
echo("</form>");
```

I added `$sql = mysql_query($result) or die (mysql_error());`

the above line  shows what time of error  the query encounted while executing... Any Ideas as to why the query is empty and wheres there is data in the table?

This Code will run upon the clicking of this link

```
echo"<a href='test.php?action=edit&id=$id'>Edit</a>";
```

Comment: Where `$id`, which is mentioned in the WHERE clause, is defined before the queries are being executed?

Answer (score 1):

You do not catch the value of `id`. As you have it written in the URL, it is transmitted via GET, the rest of your data is via POST. So you either have to transmit as a POST var as well:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id"/>
```

And catch it via PHP:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

or let it the way it is and catch it as a GET-variable:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

BUT: this code is horribly insecure. I advise you to search for `sql injection` and similar topics..

Comment: Actually, it's already in the URL. `$id = $_GET['id'];` should work.
+1 for the "horribly insecure" comment.

Comment: even though I have used $id = $_GET['id']; this query returns empty if change this>> first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',email='$email' WHERE id=$id");<< to >>WHERE id='$id'"<< it say ..... You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1 $sql = mysql_query($result) or die (mysql_error()); i have sent u an email no jobs........com

Comment: Well .. hard to say. do all the SQL-fields match the exact name in the database? eg. "last_name" and not "lastname" etc. Do target the right table? What is written if you change the `mysql_query` function to `print()` to see what is actually being sent to MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST["hdn_edit"]) && $_POST["hdn_edit"]=="edit")
{
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$id=$_POST["hdn_id"];
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',email='$email' WHERE id=$id");   
}
$sql=mysql_query("select * from user where id='$id'");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){                                             
$id = $row['id'];
$first_name = $row['first_name'];
$last_name = $row['last_name'];
$email = $row['email'];
echo("<form name='edit' method='post' action=''>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='hdn_edit' value='edit'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='hdn_id' value='$id'>");
echo("<table class=main cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5 >");
echo("<tr><td>Name: </td><td align='right'><input type='text' name='first_name' value='$first_name'></td></tr>");
echo("<tr><td>Surname: </td><td align='right'><input type='text'  name='last_name' value='$last_name'></td></tr>");
echo("<tr><td>Email: </td><td align='right'><input type='text' name='email' value='$email'></td></tr>");
echo("<tr><td></td><td><div align='right'><input type='submit'></div></td></tr>");
echo("</table>");
}
 echo("<br>");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 echo("</form>");
```

Comment: returns Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.3\www\test.php on line 50

Comment: Could you please list what change you are suggesting and why? And please try to indent the code or keep the previous indentation, and minimize the amount of posted code to what is relevant to your change? Thanks.